# Selecting Multiple .mlModel in swift

Tags: ios, swift, coreml, turi-create, mlmodel

i have multiple .mlModels in my xcode project and i want user to select the model and perform prediction

```
let gestureClassifier = GestureClassifier() //mlModel

func predictGesture(window: Int) {

    let previousOutput = modelOutputs[window]
       let modelOutput = try? gestureClassifier.prediction(features: modelInput, hiddenIn: previousOutput?.hiddenOut, cellIn: previousOutput?.cellOut)
       modelOutputs[window] = modelOutput

       if let prediction = modelOutput?.activity,
          let probability = modelOutput?.activityProbability[prediction] {
         if prediction == Config.restItValue {
           return
         }
         if probability > Config.predictionThreshold {
            if prediction == Config.chopItValue || prediction == Config.driveItValue || prediction == Config.shakeItValue {
               print("prediction: \(prediction)")
                self.recordGestures(gesture: prediction)
           }

         }
         else{

            print("unrecognised gesture")
            self.recordGestures(gesture: "unRecognised Gesture")
        }
       }
     }
```

i have an other model 
gestureClassifier1 
i would like to do something like this

```
func predictGesture(window: Int, **selectedModel**) {

      let previousOutput = modelOutputs[window]
       let modelOutput = try? **selectedModel**.prediction(features: modelInput, hiddenIn: 
   previousOutput?.hiddenOut, cellIn: previousOutput?.cellOut)

    }
```

how can i achieve this, i tried to used Anyclass as an datatype but class functions such as .prediction(..) is not accessible.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't so much a Core ML question as a general programming question: how can you make a function that accepts different types of objects but treats them in the same way?

One way to do that is to create a protocol that has the `prediction()` method in it, then create an extension for each of your `GestureClassifier` etc classes to make them conform to the protocol.

Another way is to use the `MLModel` from the `GestureClassifier`'s `.model` property and use that.